# Trouble implementing for loop to remove artist objects from matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two versions of a code to add/remove artist objects from a matplotlib figure.  The first one works fine.  I wanted to clean up the code by condensing it into for loops but when I did that it no longer worked correctly.  I'm wondering if there is something simple I might be missing here.

Non-looping version (works):

```
 def on_motion(self,event):
      if self.cback == 1:
            print "Motion Registered"
            self.xf, self.yf = event.xdata, event.ydata
            if isinstance(self.axline, lines.Line2D):
                self.ax.lines.remove(self.axline)
                self.ax.lines.remove(self.bxline)
                self.ax.lines.remove(self.ayline)
                self.ax.lines.remove(self.byline)
                self.canvas.draw()

            self.pts = []
            self.axline = lines.Line2D([self.xi, self.xf], [self.yf, self.yf])
            self.bxline = lines.Line2D([self.xi, self.xf], [self.yi, self.yi])
            self.ayline = lines.Line2D([self.xi, self.xi], [self.yi, self.yf])
            self.byline = lines.Line2D([self.xf, self.xf], [self.yi, self.yf])
            self.ax.add_line(self.axline)
            self.ax.add_line(self.bxline)
            self.ax.add_line(self.ayline)
            self.ax.add_line(self.byline)
            self.canvas.draw()
```

And here is the version with for loops which doesn't work.  When I run this version I get a `ValueError:  list.remove(x): x not in list` which occurs when the `self.ax.lines.remove(self.line[j])` line executes.  Curiously enough, this version seems to work for a few mouse movements before halting:

```
def on_motion(self,event):
        if self.cback == 1:
            print "Motion Registered"
            self.xf, self.yf = event.xdata, event.ydata
            if len(self.line) > 0 and isinstance(self.line[0], lines.Line2D):
                for j in xrange(len(self.line)):
                    self.ax.lines.remove(self.line[j])

                self.canvas.draw()

            pt_matrix = [[self.xi, self.xf, self.yf, self.yf],
                         [self.xi, self.xf, self.yi, self.yi],
                         [self.xi, self.xi, self.yi, self.yf],
                         [self.xf, self.xf, self.yi, self.yf]]

            linenew = []
            for i in xrange(4):
                linenew = lines.Line2D([pt_matrix[i][0], pt_matrix[i][1]], [pt_matrix[i][2], pt_matrix[i][3]])
                self.line.append(linenew)
                self.ax.add_line(self.line[i])

            self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: I would use the `remove` method on the `Line2D` objects instead of reaching in and touching the internals of the figure.  I suspect the problem is coming because you are triggering this twice, the first time works, the second time tries to remove an artist that has already been removed.

Comment: You also are never clearing the artists from your internal `line` list so you trying to remove already removed artists.

Comment: You will also get better performance if you update existing lines (via `set_xdata`/`set_ydata`/`set_data`) rather than removing and re-creating the artists every time (using blitting would also be a good idea).

Comment: It also looks like you are drawing a rectangle?  I would suggest using http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector or atleast using a http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle artist instead of 4 lines.

Comment: And you only need the last of your calls to `draw`